# No pre-releases in Helm search results

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When searching in my Helm repository there are no pre-releases listed in the search results

```
helm search repo

NAME              CHART VERSION    APP VERSION              DESCRIPTION
nexus/my-app      0.1.0            1.0.0                    A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

In the Nexus I can see several other versions (like `0.1.0-test123`) and also the `index.yaml` of the repository shows other versions of `my-app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `helm search` does not list pre-releases as mentioned by a Helm commiter in this [Github issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6957#issuecomment-579860064).

> Pre-release versions are hidden by default.

Using the `--devel` option will include pre-release version in the search results.

E.g.

`helm search repo --devel`